# Using Hazard Ratio to predict Population Incidence or Prevalence

Tags: hazard, ratio

The univariate hazard ratio  corresponding to a per unit continuous linear increase between a risk score and a disease is 1.04 (literature) . I am interested in using this hazard ratio to predict the current prevalence in a population I am working with who have risk scores above a certain threshold. How would I go about doing this? The paper also states that the H=1.04 is based on n=51 and 23 cases.